# Old cartoon/animated series about a child who can use magic and is adopted by an inn keeper

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Well there is a child who can use magic or something who is adopted by a pub/inn owner. He goes on adventures with a boy who has a sword with an eye. An old man. A girl who is actually an elf princess or something and her bodyguard. Unfortunately i can't remember any of their names. But what I do remember is how the boy with the sword is a berserker/demon like his father. The boy later gets married to the elf princess's bodyguard.

Answer (score 4):

This could be [*"Wakfu"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakfu_(TV_series)), a 2008 French animated series based on the homonymous MMORPG.

[image: the main characters of Wakfu]

I only have little direct knowledge of this, but the information on the Wikipedia page linked before (from which I'm going to quote a few passages) matches your description quite closely:

- **a child who can use magic or something who is adopted by a pub/inn owner**

> Yugo is a 12-year-old [...] who recently discovered his powers, and is on a mission to find his true family. He has lived with his adoptive father Alfired, working alongside him at his inn

- **He goes on adventures with a boy who has a sword with an eye**

> A 16-year-old [...], Percedal is a "Knight of the Order of the Guardians of Shushus", entrusted with the guardianship of the demon-sword Rubilax

- **An old man.**

> Ruel is an old friend of Yugo's adoptive father Alibert

- **A girl who is actually an elf princess or something and her bodyguard**
  These two would be Princess Amalia Sheran Sharm and Evangelyne.
- **the boy with the sword is a berserker/demon like his father**
  No mentions of Percedal's father, but

> As a Guardian, Percedal is responsible for making sure Rubilax does not escape its sword prison and possess its owner, or others, though when he is possessed by Rubilax he becomes a monster that is incredibly physically strong.

- **The boy later gets married to the elf princess's bodyguard**

> As the series progresses, he falls in love with Evangelyne and she with him, which later leads to them getting married.

Comment: _"Old cartoon"_. 2008. I must belong in a museum. -_-

Comment: Btw Wakfu is based on a game Wakfu, which is kind of spin-of of Dofus made by the same company. Game Dofus has its own animated series "Dofus: The treasure of Kerubim" and a movie Dofus: Book of Julith. Incidentally in the movie an older CAT innkeeper adopts a magical boy. The two of them makes token appearance in the Wakfu series. I wholeheartedly love both series and the movie has one of the best duels ever animated. The stories are equal part epic and silly. Beware thou, because French has no qualms adding things like mass murder and sexual allusions into children movies.

Comment: Percedal's father is not mentioned but we do meet his mentor who is the previous owner of the demon sword Rubilax.